# Does an object with a pending finalizer need to be collected by the GC more than one time?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalizer

I am reading the "Disposal and Garbage Collection" chapter of book C# 8.0 in a Nutshell. When it comes to finalizers, it says:

> The GC identifies the unused objects for deletion, those without
> finalizers are deleted immediately, those with pending finalizers are
> kept alive and are put onto a special queue. When the garbage
> collection is complete and your program continues executing, the
> finalizer thread then starts running in parallel to the program,
> picking objects off that special queue and running their finalization
> methods.

Does this paragraph mean that an object waiting for finalization need to be collected by the GC again? I assumed it already been detected as garbage by GC, why does it need to be collected after finalization again?

Comment: Another thing to add to the fine answers you got... I'm guessing your book pointed out that the .NET GC is a *generational* garbage collector. Gen0 collections are cheap, Gen1 much less cheap and Gen2 very expensive. If an object gets finalized, it misses its chance to be Gen0 collected (since it can only be collectedafter the finalizer runs). Another reason to make sure that objects don't need finalization when used correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the objects were not 'collected' the first time. They were seen to need additional processing (finalizer code needs to run) and put on the finalization queue so they could be processed separately. This ends up putting them on the 'freachable' queue, which has now resurrected the object: it is now referenced by the freachable queue and is no longer eligible for collection. It will be unreachable after the finalizer actually executes and the object is removed from the freachable queue.

(This is how it used to work, not sure if things have changed in newer .NET versions, but I'm not aware of any.)

So the object is not really 'collected' more than once, if by 'collected' we understand that the memory was reclaimed. It does, however, need additional processing and will be re-evaluated by the GC again at a later point in time.

Comment: There's no strict definition of these terms. Often, the term "collecting" is used when referring to the act of identifying the reachable and in turn the unreachable objects, whereas "reclaiming" refers to enabling the reuse of the object's memory. In that regard, the object with a finalizer will be collected twice. However, given that normally, a garbage collector doesn't deal with the unreachable objects, but moves the survivors to a new memory location, which must be done for the finalizable objects too, it's fair to say that these objects were not collected at all, actually.

Answer (score 3):

The GC works by traversing object graphs from GC roots.  When the GC does a collection it checks for objects that have no references to it (and are therefore safe to free up).

A finalizer delays garbage collection of objects.

Why?  Well the GC sees that an object is safe to be free'd up (not connected to a GC root).  However, it can't free the memory if there's a finalizer that hasn't run yet.

So the GC **marks** the object as having a pending finalizer and does *not* free up that space on first pass.  Nor does the GC run the finalizer at that instant (it puts it in a "pending finalizer" queue).

This is exactly why it's bad practice to use finalizers unless necessary.  It delays collection.  Some have a misconception that the GC runs the finalizer upon a collection pass.  It does not.

When is it necessary?  A good rule of thumb is if the objects references unmanaged memory (which is not handled by the GC) then you absolutely should use a finalizer to avoid memory leaks.  If you're only referencing managed objects then don't.

If you do implement a finalizer I would also implement `IDisposable`, release any unmanaged resources on `Dispose` and stop the finalizer ever from running with [`GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: And to add to the last paragraph, if you do have a class that manages unmanaged  resources (not just memory), and you do have a finalizer, make sure your `Dispose` method aggressively releases those resources and then marks the object as no longer needing Finalizer (`GC.SupressFinalization`). That way, the object no longer needs special handling by the GC and can be collected just like any other object

Comment: I'm very sure that C# does not use reference counting. The term doesn't even fit into you answer, as you are describing the logic of a traversing garbage collector, i.e whether an object is reachable from a root.

Comment: @Holger Traversing an object graph is [how the GC works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/automatic-memory-management#releasing-memory), sure.  But that _is_ effectively reference counting.  I didn't say using an internal counter or something.  Specifically, the GC wants to know if the reference count is zero or not.  It's an implementation detail, really.  Functionally equivalent.

Comment: No, [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is an established term with a specific meaning. And it's not helpful for the future readers, to use a technical term in a different way than the rest of the world.